# Loading line as a code?

Tags: php

Ok, I've got class with function that is load text from txt file. Function load line `print "Some kind of text"`, but I want to run this (so I'll got `Some kind of text`)

```
<?php

 class LoadFile
 {
  //Funkcja to load file
  public function wykonaj()
  {
   $fp = fopen("link", "r");
   $tekst = fread($fp, 25); 
   $szukaj = "print"

   echo $tekst;   
  }
 }

 $Test = new LoadFile();
 $Test->wykonaj(); 
 ?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume what you want to do is to use the file as a PHP script. Why not use proper includes then?

Another solution is to use the [eval()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php) function, but then look at the doc carefully and be aware how dangerous it is.

Comment: Function eval() works, but what if I want run txt file with math (e.g. random) or date function? When I use eval(), I've empty site.

Comment: The empty site comes from your PHP settings concerning displaying error messages, and you may want to look at your log files then or reconfigure PHP (http://www.dzone.com/snippets/let-php-show-all-errors).

Comment: I try put this code:

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');

but it still don't work.

Comment: For some reasons your code does not display...

Comment: I know, but even run error_reporting I still don't get error message. Maybe something in my code stop error_reporting?