# Does eval work with date function and math function (e.g. rand)?

Tags: php

So I have code which load one of txt file, which include one of this line:

- print "text";
- rand(1,25);
- date("F j, Y, g:i a");

When I run this code, print "text" line works correctly, however rand and date give me just blank page.

Even using error capturing code I vave no any error message.

Comment: why not converrt the txt file to a php file ?

Comment: **Pro Tip:** Supplying the code you "tried" will help in debugging.

Comment: <?php

 class LoadFile
 {
  //Funkcja to load file
  public function wykonaj()
  {
   $fp = fopen("link", "r");
   $tekst = fread($fp, 50); 

   eval ($tekst);

   fclose($fp);   

  }
 }

 $Test = new LoadFile();
 $Test->wykonaj(); 
 ?>

Comment: Did you take that code from [`this question`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25109676/2518525) ?

Comment: Yes, cause I work with this code too.

Comment: I put eval function into variable $do, and in next line print this variable, but it still don't work.

Comment: @user3904787 See my answer for how to do it with a variable.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're running

```
eval("rand(1,25);");
```

for example, which will simply call that function and discard the return value. You need the print statement for every call to see the result in the output:

```
eval("print rand(1,25);");
```

An alternative is to use `return`:

```
$result = eval("return rand(1,25);");
print $result;
```